# Which oracle database user to use for creating tables, procedures, views, deleting those and insert into tables

Tags: oracle, ddl, privileges

I have to know which user have developer's roles and privileges, how to connect him to my pluggable database and allow him to create, delete, drop, **insert into tables** ,create and drop procedures/functions/views .
and in my connection in my app jdbc which user can i use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this your database, and by that I mean, did YOU create it?

Then the answer is, you need to create at least one schema for your application, and maybe perhaps as many as three.

Is this someone else's database? If so, they should give you credentials for the account you are meant to use.

Assuming this is a database you yourself just created, it's very important that you do NOT use these default admin accounts for you to do your application work in:

- SYSTEM
- SYS

Instead, use these accounts to create a user for your application.

Note that this USER will be able to do anything it wants to any object it owns (the SCHEMA).

For this reason, you often find this sort of layout for applications in an Oracle Database:

1. a schema for the application data (tables, views, materialized views)
2. a schema for the application code (PL/SQL and maybe stored Java procedures)
3. a schema for the application user

NO ONE gets to login as the application schema.

The stored procedures in the second schema are only given the privs absolutely necessary to do their job - READ/SELECT on a table perhaps, but not INSERT or UPDATE if it's just a proc to get data back.

The 3rd schema is only given execute privs on the 2nd schema.

If you create a user, they can do any/all of the things you mention -

> create, delete, drop, insert into tables ,create and drop
>   procedures/functions/views

But they won't be able to do anything to objects/data in another schema unless you grant them the ability to do so. And in most cases, you would NOT do so. You'd write a PL/SQL API that does this work, and then grant execute privs on this API to your APP user.